# Documentation on writing buildout recipes

Tags: python, buildout, recipe

I am trying to find tutorials on how to write buildout recipes. I haven't found any, except the one on buildout site. But it is very rudimentary. Is there a good tutorial for writing buildout recipes?

Answer (score 4):

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/ZopeSkel/ has a template for a buildout recipe.  That at least gets you started regarding having a skeleton for adding your own code.

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/zc.buildout#id1 has *some* information on which methods you need to implement.

Best way to learn it is by looking at an existing recipe to see how it gets done. I'd suggest my own recipe :-) :

https://svn.plone.org/svn/collective/buildout/collective.recipe.backup/trunk/

Comment: This works out for most part, but I will keep looking. I am going through source code of all the highly rated buildout recipes to understand a general pattern. If I get some good work done, I will upload it to cheeseshop. BTW, I am writing a recipe to create paster templates(ie, invoke paster create command, and pass in values, but not through command line), more on the line of infrae.paster(which doesn't recognize 3.3.4 and 4.0bx plones.). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2894455/automate-paster-create-t-plone3-buildout

Answer (score 0):

A quick google search came back with the following:

http://docs.plone.org/old-reference-manuals/buildout/creating.html

And the answers in the following Stack Overflow question look pretty helpful as well:

[Better resources to learn buildout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369664/better-resources-to-learn-buildout)

Comment: I can write a buildout. I want to write a custom recipe, to do some work in buildout. So I want to learn, how to write a recipe. Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a short tutorial with basic information http://grok.zope.org/documentation/tutorial/introduction-to-zc.buildout/writing-your-own-recipes